# React state lagging behind reality, causing MUI to display wrong dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

On a button, I have a onClick handler

```
  const handleSelectOpen = (noteId) => {
    let newState = {notes: state.notes, noteDetailScreen: true, activeNote: noteId, newNoteScreen: false, newNoteText: "", newNoteRelated: []};
    setState(newState);
  };
```

Which does two important things, it sets noteDetailScreen in the state to true, causing the [MUI Dialog](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/) to appear. It also sets activeNote to noteId, which is the content that should be displayed in the dialog.

That content is then displayed with {state.notes[state.activeNote].content} inside the dialog. The issue being most of the time, its displaying the wrong content! noteId is always correct, but the state is not always correct. How can I fix this>

Comment: Update: It seems {state.notes[state.activeNote].content} is the issue, {state.activeNote} displays the correct number, it just doesn't work when used as an array selector like that. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

when updating state based on the previous state, you should pass an updater function to setState. It takes the pending state and calculates the next state from it.

```js
setState(prev => ({notes: prev.notes, noteDetailScreen: true, activeNote: noteId, newNoteScreen: false, newNoteText: "", newNoteRelated: []}))
```

Comment: Interesting! It does not fix the problem however, the state in dialog is still lagging behind.

Comment: can you share a minimal reproducible example?